# How to find whether an Android stack in phone is Original or Jail-broken?

Tags: android, root, jailbreak

I would like to know how to find whether an Android stack in phone is Original or Jail-broken?

**My Intention :**
My application will check for the genuineness of the Android OS in phone.
If it finds that, the phone does not have a genuine Android, it will not allow the application to install on phone.

Is it possible to implement this?

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: In Android this is called 'rooting' a phone (jailbreaking is rather for iPhones), because you get root access on the device. Maybe test if you have write rights on some system file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you can "su" on the phone with an installer application. If you can't, install your apk as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent installation of your app - there are no pre-install hooks for you to do that.

What you can do however, is use @Nacho L's method once installed to prevent your app from running.

Of course, if the phone is rooted, then there's nothing you can do to prevent your app from running if the user is determined to run it.